# Why does apt-get upgrade cause blank screen after reboot on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, apt

I have Raspberry 2 B, installed the [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) . Everything was good. However, when I ran

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

it took about 50minues, and after reboot, i have blank screen with blinking horizontal cursor. I can SSH and work commands, but no GUI.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, how to avoid it, and possibly shed some information on this matter?

Comment: I don't see how anyone can know what happened.  You are in the best position to troubleshoot and find the root cause.

Comment: But i have no knowledge of how i could do that :(

Comment: As joan mentioned this question is too broad. You should back up ANY computer system before doing a major change. The GUI on the Pi seems to be VERY sensitive to errors - either configuration or in the widgets. You could do an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` again (which should be much faster).

Comment: Can you tell me how to narrow it down? I can quote exact items and version I have.

Answer (score 1):

If none of those other options work, and you don't have any important files, you could always reformat the sd card and download a new version of raspian on it.  However, I would only do this as a last resort if nothing else is working.  You could also try and back up whatever you have left before you do this.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i was forced to do that. But anytime i run `sudo apt-get upgrade` i end up in the darkness...

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. I was trying to do `sudo apt-get upgrade` over WiFi dongle. However, the WiFi dongle didn't have good connection and things were dropping and apparently files were missing or were badly downloaded and as a result the os broke every time.

Also, my card was 16 GB, but the image was for 4 GB, so I had to expand the partition to take all the space (I saw somewhere errors for space too)

I connected it through Ethernet, ran again and everything was good.